# Error en Restoring Backup Postgres

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-13, postgresql-10

Estoy tratando de restaurar mi base de datos pero se me presenta el siguiente error, el archivo que tengo para la restauración es solamente datos ya las tablas y los schemas los tengo creados.
Si alguien le paso el mismo error, gracias de antemano
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tienes forma de ver más detalles del error? Así como está sólo se ve el -1 que es el error genérico. Lo otro, son relevantes las etiquetas de postgresql13 y 10? Estás migrando entre versiones diferentes?? Si necesitas ajustar, recuerda que puedes [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Por alguna razón el error al tratar de restaurar los datos desde el agente web pgadmin4.2 no me permitía realizar esta acción así que utilice el siguiente comando directo directamente por consola

**pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d old_db -v
"/public/backups/csv_datos_data-2022-01-20.backup"**